# ClusterManager Google Map Utility V2 iterating through a cluster

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working with the Google Maps Utility v2 / ClusterManager for Android.  There is very little documentation on this, but for the most part I have it all working.  I was just about to implement the `OnClusterClickListener` Which i had assumed would allow me to iterate through the cluster..

ie:

mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(new OnClusterClickListener(){

```
            @Override
            public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<mObject> cluster) {
                for(int i =0; i<cluster.size(); i++){
                      Log.v("CLUSTER", "mObject's certain property is:"+ cluster.get(i).mProperty);

                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

But apparently that is not the case..  the cluster only has a few public methods as seen in the image below, and with no documentation that i can find, I was hoping someone had experience with this utility and could get me over this stupid hump.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like

```
for (DRPDrop drop : cluster.getItems()) {
    // do things with your object
}
```

should work to iterate over your implementation of `ClusterItem`.